# How to show selected cell data at the middle of the screen if i have taken horizontal collection view

Tags: swift

I am working on TV music application and there I am getting around 62 channels which I am showing in collectionView and when I select any cell(channel) then i am navigating to other screen. Now on that screen I want to show that selected cell in the mid of screen and it should be highlighted(on the other screen also I am showing all channels in horizontal collectionView).Suppose if have selected 20th cell then 0 to 19 cell should be left side and 20th cell should be in the mid of screen with highlighting effect.

```
extension PlayerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.channelCount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()

        }
        let channel = self.viewModel.channels[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(channel)
        if let url = URL(string: channel.coverImage ?? "") {
                   Nuke.loadImage(
                       with: url,
                       options: ImageLoadingOptions(
                           placeholder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "channelPlaceholder"),
                           transition: .fadeIn(duration: 0.33),
                           failureImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "channelPlaceholder")
                       ),
                       into: self.backgroundImageView)
               }else {
            self.backgroundImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "channelPlaceholder")
               }
        return cell
    }
    override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
        return [collectionView]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {

        return true
    }


}

    extension PlayerViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 40
        }
    }
```

Comment: please check my answer and mark it as approved if it is helpful to you. So it will be helpful to others who have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

at collection view's `didSelectItem` func

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: @ShubhangiSingh

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scrollToItem()` method of `UICollectionView` to scroll cell horizontally.

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

And make sure your `UICollectionView` has enabled the `pagination` property to show cell in the middle of the screen.

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```